# Filtering out results from a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a data set that looks like this:

```json
teams = [
    {
        "teamName": "Alpha",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Jane",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    },
    {
        "teamName": "Beta",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    }
]
```

I'm trying to implement a search function against a said list by firstName + lastName combo. So far I've tried:

```js
searchTerm = 'John Doe';
teams.filter(team => 
   team.members.some(member => 
      (member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName).includes(searchTerm)
   )
);
```

I'm expecting for that to return the following:

```json
[
    {
        "teamName": "Alpha",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    },
    {
        "teamName": "Beta",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    }
]
```

But the code seems to be returning the teams that John Doe is part of without filtering Jane Doe out.

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

```js
const teams = [
    {
        "teamName": "Alpha",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Jane",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    },
    {
        "teamName": "Beta",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    }
]

searchTerm = 'John Doe';
console.log(teams.filter(team => 
   team.members.some(member => 
      (member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName).includes(searchTerm)
   )
));
```

Comment: Your filter filters out teams that don't have a member named `John Doe`. It doesn't filter team members.

Comment: Your new `"members": [` makes absolutely no sense. Since you already know who you're looking for, a simple result like `["Alpha", "Beta"]` seems better. or rather: `{teams: [], member: {}}`

Comment: Currently the question is unclear for me. Do you want to filter only members and always list all teams or do you want to filter members and teams. What's the expected result if you search for `Jane Doe`?

Comment: You should read https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I need to retain the team that the user is part of for the front-end so if I was to look for Jane Doe I'd expect result to come back as:
```
[
    {
        "teamName": "Alpha",
        "members": [
            {
                "firstName": "Jan",
                "lastName": "Doe"
            }
        ]   
    }
]
```

Comment: But that's not the result in the accepted answer. It returns all teams, even teams with empty member lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve the desired result.

```
const result = teams.map((t) => {
  return {
    ...t,
    members: t.members.filter(
      (m) => `${m.firstName} ${m.lastName}` === searchTerm
    ),
  };
});
```

```js
const teams = [
  {
    teamName: "Alpha",
    members: [
      {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
      },
      {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    teamName: "Beta",
    members: [
      {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const searchTerm = "John Doe";

const result = teams.map((t) => {
  return {
    ...t,
    members: t.members.filter(
      (m) => `${m.firstName} ${m.lastName}` === searchTerm
    ),
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP added all details, he shown what he has tried and I gave two solutions

Comment: @RemiVainoris I've added two solutions

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis: Search through answer history for `const [first, last] = searchTerm.split(" ")`: what if someone has two words in first name or two words in last name? That solution would've broken pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by using lodash.

```js
const searchTerm = 'John Doe'
const result = _.map(teams, elem => {
    elem.members = _.filter(elem.members, ({firstName, lastName}) => `${firstName} ${lastName}` === searchTerm);
    return elem;
});

console.log('result', result)
```

This is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/9o8mx0rh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Plz try to do like this:

```js
searchTerm = 'John Doe';
teams.map(team => 
   team.members.filter(member => 
      (member.firstName + ' ' + member.lastName).includes(searchTerm)
   )
);
```